# How do I convert this timestamp to PHP? Bing Maps API

Tags: php, json, api, timestamp

I've been playing around with the Bing API using json and PHP. The array spits out the following for dates:

```
[end] => /Date(1354867200000)/
[lastModified] => /Date(1349441488000)/
```

I thought this was a unix timestamp, but it I don't think it is. What I did was a preg_replace like this

```
$last_updated = $resource->lastModified;
$last_updated_timestamp = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]*/','',$last_updated);
```

Then tried to convert it to a date

```
$last_updated_date = date('l F d Y g:i:s A',$last_updated_timestamp);
```

The results that it's showing me for date range back from the year 1967 to 2000. Is this a different kind of timestamp that I don't know of? If so, how do I correct this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number part is milliseconds-since-the-Epoch (January 1, 1970 at midnight — the milliseconds version of a unix timestamp). This is a fairly conventional way to represent dates in JSON (since JSON doesn't have a date type).

So `getdate(theNumber / 1000)` will give you the date (since [`getdate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) expects seconds, not milliseconds, since The Epoch).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but something still seems a little off. With the Bing Maps API, it should be showing up to date things, but the times are showing me all sorts of random June 29 - October 29 2012. They're all in a random order. I'd think that Microsoft would have more sense to order them in descending and to provide up to date information no? 

Code looks like this:

 $last_updated = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]*/','',$last_updated);
 $last_updated = getdate($last_updated / 1000); 
 $last_updated_timestamp = $last_updated[0];
 $last_updated_date = date('l F d Y g:i:s A',$last_updated_timestamp);

Comment: @user1701252 Here you have some information on how `date()` works if you haven't already.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php The mixed dates may be coming from date formats that are probably formatted wrong.

Comment: @user1701252: I can't help you with Bing or with whether Microsoft does things in a rational way. :-) I can tell you that `/Date(nnnn)/` is **the** standard way to represent dates in JSON, and that `nnnn` is milliseconds-since-the-Epoch. The first date in your question is 07-Dec-2012 at midnight GMT. The second date in your question is 05-Oct-2012 at 12:51:28 GMT (to me, 13:51:28 British Summer Time).

Comment: Just tested it on another city and it works just fine. As for the formatting, I will take a look into that and see if it works better with something a little more simple. THANK YOU ALL for such QUICK responses.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is convert a unix timestamp to date format, you can do it by doing the following:

```
date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($unix_timestamp));
```

Where `$unix_timestamp` is your unix timestamp in this case.
You can always print it out for testing purposes by adding `echo` before it.

So in this case it could be:

```
$last_updated_date = date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($last_updated_timestamp));
```